# Tkinter cannot place Label Frame at the top of a window

Tags: python, tkinter, label

My issue is that my second Label Frame wont move past halfway,I expected the top of both frames to be in line with each other so they could be side by side however the second gets place half way down the application. I have looked through the code and cant see anything taking its place, can anyone help out? I know this code might not be the most efficient but it is currently kind of acting as a building block for a bigger project, I hope to improve it as I create the program further so any suggestions would be awesome.

[My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXeH.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3
from random import randint

def available():
    print("works")

ref = ""
for x in range(0,9):
    ref = ref + str(randint(0,9))enter code here

    ####VARS####
    master = Tk()
    master.geometry('700x700+500+100')
    master.title('Booking System | Ref: ' + ref)
    carvar = StringVar(master)
    carvar.set("Select Option")
    typevar = StringVar(master)
    typevar.set("Select Option")
    statusvar = StringVar(master)
    statusvar.set("Select Option")
    ############

    #booking consts#
    blpadx = (0,10)
    bepadx = (0,5)


    #Column 0
    booking = LabelFrame(master, text="Booking Information", padx=5, pady=5)
    booking.grid(padx=(20,10), pady=(20,10), column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
    dateFrom = Label(booking, text="Book From:")
    dateFrom.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0),sticky=W)
    days = Label(booking, text="Days:")
    days.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    dateTo = Label(booking, text="Book To:")
    dateTo.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    rooms = Label(booking, text="Rooms:")
    rooms.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    car = Label(booking, text="Car:")
    car.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    stayType = Label(booking, text="Stay Type:")
    stayType.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    bookStatus = Label(booking, text="Booking Status:")
    bookStatus.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
    bHrRule = ttk.Separator(booking, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    bHrRule.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=2, sticky=EW,pady=(15,15))
    availableInfo = Label(booking, text="Click Check Availability to show the room types\n available between the selected dates.")
    availableInfo.grid(column=0, row=8, padx=blpadx, pady=(0,10), columnspan=2)
    available = Button(booking, text="Check Availability", command=available)
    available.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=2, pady=(0,15))



    #Column 1
    dateFromEntry = Entry(booking)
    dateFromEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    dateFromEntry.insert(END, "DD/MM/YYYY") 
    daysEntry = Entry(booking)
    daysEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    dateToEntry = Entry(booking)
    dateToEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    dateToEntry.insert(END, "DD/MM/YYYY") 
    roomsEntry = Entry(booking)
    roomsEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    carEntry = OptionMenu(booking,carvar, "No", "Yes")
    carEntry.config(width=15)
    carEntry.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    stayType = OptionMenu(booking,typevar, "Self Catering", "All-Inclusive")
    stayType.config(width=15)
    stayType.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    bookStatus = OptionMenu(booking,statusvar, "placeholder", "same")
    bookStatus.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
    bookStatus.config(width=15)

    #Column 2
    customer = LabelFrame(master, text="Customer Details", padx=5, pady=5)
    customer.grid(padx=(0,0), pady=(0,0), column=2, row=0)
    title = Label(customer, text="Book From:")
    title.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0),sticky=W)

    #Shoop De Loop
    mainloop()
```

Comment: your code doesn't run. It has several errors. Your code doesn't define `ref` before using it. You also create a button with the command `available`, and then you store the button in a variable named `available`. This means that a) the code won't work because you use `available` before it's defined, and b) if it did work, the button would simply try to call itself.

Comment: What does "won't move past half-way" mean? Half way from what or to what? Half-way up? To the left? Do you expect the top to align with the other frame? The bottom?

Comment: I left some of the code out, I will edit the post.

Comment: I expected the top of both frames to be in line with each other, so the frames would be side by side, sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the labelframe `customer`, you're only using a `sticky` of `W`. That means it will stick to the left side of the space it has been given, but not the top and bottom. You need to include "N" if you want it to stick to the top of it's given space.

Here's a suggestion to make these problems easier to spot group all of your layout code together. Instead of widget, layout, widget, layout, put all the widgets together and then all the layout together.

I also recommend laying out all siblings together. So, layout the labelframes first, and then the other widgets in each frame.

For example:

```
#Column 0
booking = LabelFrame(master, text="Booking Information", padx=5, pady=5)
dateFrom = Label(booking, text="Book From:")
days = Label(booking, text="Days:")
dateTo = Label(booking, text="Book To:")
rooms = Label(booking, text="Rooms:")
car = Label(booking, text="Car:")
stayType = Label(booking, text="Stay Type:")
bookStatus = Label(booking, text="Booking Status:")
bHrRule = ttk.Separator(booking, orient=HORIZONTAL)
availableInfo = Label(booking, text="Click Check Availability to show the room types\n available between the selected dates.")
available = Button(booking, text="Check Availability")

#Column 1
dateFromEntry = Entry(booking)
dateFromEntry.insert(END, "DD/MM/YYYY") 
daysEntry = Entry(booking)
dateToEntry = Entry(booking)
dateToEntry.insert(END, "DD/MM/YYYY") 
roomsEntry = Entry(booking)
carEntry = OptionMenu(booking,carvar, "No", "Yes")
carEntry.config(width=15)
stayType = OptionMenu(booking,typevar, "Self Catering", "All-Inclusive")
stayType.config(width=15)
bookStatus = OptionMenu(booking,statusvar, "placeholder", "same")
bookStatus.config(width=15)

#Column 2
customer = LabelFrame(master, text="Customer fooDetails", padx=5, pady=5)
title = Label(customer, text="Book From:")

booking.grid(padx=(20,10), pady=(20,10), column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)
customer.grid(padx=(0,0), pady=(0,0), column=2, row=0, sticky="N")

# booking
dateFrom.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0),sticky=W)
dateFromEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
dateTo.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
days.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
rooms.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
car.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
stayType.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
bookStatus.grid(column=0, row=6, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0), sticky=W)
bHrRule.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=2, sticky=EW,pady=(15,15))
availableInfo.grid(column=0, row=8, padx=blpadx, pady=(0,10), columnspan=2)
available.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=2, pady=(0,15))

daysEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
dateToEntry.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
roomsEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
carEntry.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
stayType.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))
bookStatus.grid(column=1, row=6, padx=bepadx, pady=(5,0))

# customer
title.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=blpadx, pady=(5,0))
```

That's not necessarily *exactly* how I would do it, but the point is to logically group your code so you can focus just on layout, or just on widget objects, and not have to deal with it all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had it in my head for some reason that the sticky did something else and thought about changing it but didn't. Will do more testing in the future if I have problems